# Animate 20 SKSprites in sequence

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I want to introduce in my SKScene a certain amount of different SKSprites, and I want them to appear from left (initial position x=-70, outside screen) and move to the correct position (final position x=40) one after the other at the scene presentation. At the end all the sprites should be one over the other, and only the last one should be visible (like a deck of card i.e.).

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
SKAction *move=[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(40, self.frame.size.height-70) duration:1];
SKAction *wait=[SKAction waitForDuration:1.5];
SKAction *sequence=[SKAction sequence:@[move,wait]];

for (anObject in myArray){
    SKSpriteNode *aSprite=[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:myTexture];
    aSprite.position=CGPointMake(-60, self.frame.size.height-70);
    aSprite.zPosition=z;
    aSprite.xScale=0.1;
    aSprite.yScale=0.1;
    aSprite.name=[anObject.image];
    [self addChild:aSprite];
    [aSprite runAction:sequence];
    }
```

But I'm able to see only one sprite moving... I'm not able to figure out what's wrong and how to fix it. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: how many objects are in myArray defines how many sprites you create

Comment: Sorry, aRetro=aSprite. I've fixed the typo. Thanks

Comment: You are seeing only one sprite because they are all stacked on top of each other. They are stacked because the sprites are created nearly at the same time when you return control to the run loop. I suggest you 1) implement a method that creates a sprite, adds it to the scene, and runs the action on it, 2) create an action that calls the method (with performSelector) and then waits 1.5 seconds, and 3) run that action with repeatAction:count.

Comment: Thank you! I followed your suggestions and everything is fine now.